# Is Blender a good solution for bringing hand drawn illustrations to 3D life?

Tags: animation

I'm completely unfamiliar with animation, but I'm considering learning blender for use in producing educational (physics) content as it was suggested to me that it can be used to do what Henry Reich does in the following MinutePhysics video from 00:53-00:58:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmNXKqeUtJM

Would "bringing hand drawn animation to 3D life" in the particular way illustrated by this video be relatively straightforward in Blender?  Is Blender a good solution for attempting to recreate that sort of thing?

Comment: I think they are using Sparkol's VideoScribe to make their content.
http://www.videoscribe.co/scribes This guy does some cool looking stuff in Blender for 2D art... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYwxHEHoLeE&list=PLeeE9RhUxh80Q031qslEL0LfrvhUp4d5t Or how about import drawings as svg then use the Build modifier to animate the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly could. [Import](https://vimeo.com/17965710) your "hand drawn" textures on to planes. Then just position them in 3D space. Animate the camera moving around and your effect is about done. Depending on how much movement you may want to add a [Track To Constraint](http://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html) to each of your planes, set the constraint to the camera. That will make the planes always point at the camera.

Comment: Thanks David.  I'm also trying to get a sense of whether Blender would be overkill for doing this sort of thing; do you have an opinion in that regard?

Comment: @joshphysics That would depend on what are your other options for software. For the effect in the linked video, I would ether use after effects or blender (probably blender).  I would not call Blender "overkill", it would work great for this.

Comment: Ok cool.  I actually happen to have access to after effects as well, but based on my current (quite limited) impressions, Blender seems like a better solution.

Comment: For many planes being simulated like in the example video, you might want to use particles and physics to animate them.

Answer (score 1):

### Handwriting Tool in BTrace Addon

You can animate handwriting and drawing in Blender using the Handwriting Tool in the [BTrace addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Btrace). According to the documentation, it "creates an animated curve using the grease pencil." Although I have not used it yet, it looks like it is designed to animate hand-drawn illustrations, just as shown in the video you mention.

There is also a demonstration video there [on the documentation page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Btrace).